# Why the array is showing 0 as result?

Tags: java, arrays

1. why output is null

   ```
   package HackerRank;

   import java.util.Scanner;

   import java.util.*;

   public class reverseArray {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
       int x =sc.nextInt();
       int j=x;
       int[] array= new int[x];
       int[] reverse=new int[x];

       for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
       {
           array[i]=sc.nextInt();
       }
       for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
       {
           array[j-1]=reverse[i];
           j-=1;
       }
       for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
           System.out.println(reverse[i]);
       }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just switch operands.

```
array[j-1]=reverse[i];
```

Should be :

```
reverse[i]=array[j-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second for loop you're assigning wrong in your reverse array. It must be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    reverse[j - 1] = array[i];
    j -= 1;
}
```